# In Julia: Is there a way to test for equality like R's all.equal()?

Tags: julia

Take this `R` example:

```
> x = 0.5 - 0.3
> y = 0.3 - 0.1
> x == y         # although mathematically TRUE, it’s FALSE for limited precision
[1] FALSE
> all.equal(x,y) # equal up to precision of computer
[1] TRUE
```

To quote from R documentation:

> ‘all.equal(x, y)’ is a utility to compare R objects ‘x’ and ‘y’
>        testing ‘near equality’.  If they are different, comparison is
>        still made to some extent, and a report of the differences is
>        returned.  Do not use ‘all.equal’ directly in ‘if’
>        expressions-either use ‘isTRUE(all.equal(....))’ or ‘identical’ if
>        appropriate.

In `Julia`, `x == y` will return `false`. Is there a way to check this equality up to machine precision in Julia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`isapprox(x,y)` is what you are looking for.

use `?isapprox` in the REPL for additional help. Specifically, 2 parameters which specify relative tolerance for error and absolute tolerance for error.

Happy 2016

Comment: `\approx` which turns to the unicode operator `≈` is a neat shorthand. `x≈y == true`

Comment: you just write the right answer before me, so I delete mine. Happy 2016

Comment: Yeah. Even the wording was the same (enough for isapprox). ;)

Comment: I wish a complete 2016 profile instead of an air of mystery for you.Thanks for all things you've taught me in the last year.

Comment: Thank you very much, a little bit by bit makes `Julia` a great language. Happy and good luck in 2016!